# Syntax of name attributes in HTML input elements

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have tried Ruby (and Rails) earlier and when I created the views I used a syntax like this in the input fields:

```
<input name="fruit[name]" .../>

<input name="fruit[traits][]" .../>
```

and so on. The first one would give me a `fruit`key in the params hash and so on. Now that I have shifted to Node.js and Express I can use the same syntax in the name attribute and I get a nice object `fruit` in the request objects body property (using the bodyParser middelware).

Now I wonder, is it written in the spec that the given formats in the name attribute should create such a structure in the request params/body property? Or is this something that everyone just do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I wonder, is it written in the spec that the given formats in the name attribute should create such a structure in the request params/body property?

No

> Or is this something that everyone just do?

It started in PHP. A few other form parsers have copied the behaviour.